# Как подключить директиву vue в Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js

У меня есть библиотека, которую я хочу подружить с Nuxt 3.

Для этого я создал дефолтный проект Nuxt модуля по документации: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/modules.

```
import { defineNuxtModule } from "@nuxt/kit";
import lib from "some-lib";

// Module options TypeScript interface definition
export interface ModuleOptions {}

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: "some-lib",
  },
  // Default configuration options of the Nuxt module
  defaults: {
    arr: [],
    dirName: "custom-dir",
  },
  setup(options, nuxt) {
    // ?????????????
  },
});
```

Я знаю, что можно использовать `addPlugin(...)` и там есть доступ и экземпляру `Vue`.
Но я не знаю, как прокинуть туда опции `options` из `setup`.

Чтобы использование было такое:

*/nuxt.config.ts*

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    [
      "module",
      {
        arr: [],
        dirName: "custom-dir",
      },
    ],
  ],
});
```

Такое чувство, что я что-то упускаю...